# Any "IF" Statement for Segues Based on Cell Selected?

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am wanting to know if there is any way to impose an if statement using the same segue. Basically I want the same view for the table to go to but based on the cell selected, I would like it to carry with it different data that is relevant to the users selection. Such as if the user selects Dallas in the table it shouldn't show info on New York.

Do I create 100 segues from one view to the next or is there a way for it to carry data relevant based on an if statement?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can use the same segue, and pass the information you want to display on the next view controller according  the selected cell. There is no need to create 100 seagues.

Comment: How do I use the same segue to pass on data based on cell selection is what im asking. Any code or pointers? Im not sure how to say if Dallas load this list vs if New York load this other list.

Comment: I have posted an answer, check if it can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
> {
>     // Assume self.view is the table view
>     NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
>     DetailObject *detail = [self detailForIndexPath:path];
>     [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:detail];
> }
> ```

depending on the selection of cell just pass the information or object you want to display on view controller.

Comment: What is DetailObject here? Im getting an error on it. Use of undeclared identifier detail. I simply copy and pasted the line. WOuld I do something like If (path == o) then display this list?

Comment: DetailObject is the object you want to refer to next view controller.

Comment: Thank you very much Will. Im just not sure how to say this list appear instead of any of the other 10 using that. Is it possible to just put if (path == 0) { launch this list} else if (path == 1) {launch this list instead}?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it....

1. When you create a segue, u give an identifier to it.
2. When u perform a segue, the following method gets called, so override it

something like this,

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Identifier of your segue"]) {

    //Access the destination controller by, You can cast it to your custom controller class
    UIViewController *destination =  segue.destinationViewController;

    //Do what u want

    }
}
```

So I believe, u want to go to a specific view when a cell in the table gets selected,
You need to create the segue from the controller which has the table to the controller you want to go to. Don't create the segue from the cell to the controller.

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can perform the segue using this...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your segue Identifier" sender:self];
```

The `prepareForSegue:sender` will anyways be called and you can set the data for the destination controller. You now have only one segue.

For more info [Refer this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I find that will only work for one segue. So if I have a segue identified as "first" and want to call second using that code it crashed saying second doesnt exist. Unless I understood wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ctr+drag from your tablviewcontroller to detailview and give identifier to segue and use following method

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
  }
```